# Reading in a filename from echo command in C

Tags: c

I was wondering what's the best way to read in a filename in C when the name is echoed on the command line, as in: if I type in

```
echo test.txt | a1
```

how would I access the `test.txt` using 
`fopen(fname, "r");`?

Comment: You'd be reading the string `"test.txt"` from the standard input. So you'd need to use the C library to read the standard input.

Comment: can i get a example of how to use fgets()

Comment: @timmmyjohnson Are you the same person as pillow pants, or are you working on the same homework assignment? There's [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939914/reading-in-filename-using-echo-and-using-the-file) that sounds identical to yours, except the other poster actually posted what they tried. It is generally polite to mention that you are working on a homework assignment, so that people don't just solve your problem for you directly, but instead point you in the right direction to solve it yourself, as homework is supposed to give you practice solving problems.

Comment: Note that `a1.c` would normally be the source for a C program (or part of the source for it), so I've reworked your command line to reference a program `a1` (which might be compiled from `a1.c`).  Does your machine not have manual pages available?  You can find the POSIX specification for [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) online.  The main thing to remember is that the input string will include the newline unless the line is too long (but the file name won't need the newline, so you'll need to remove it before opening the file).

Comment: Also, it is often easier to read the file name(s) from the argument list: `a1 test.txt`.  This is often a more flexible way for programs to work.  Look up [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) or its GNU relatives (`getopt()` and `getopt_long()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read data from the standard input.
2. Process the data.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char buf[1024];

while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
{
    printf("Read line: '%s'\n", buf);

    FILE * fp = fopen(buf, "r");

    if (fp)
    {
        // process the file
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No such file: %s\n", buf);
    }
}
```

The obvious caveat is that the file name may be longer than 1023 characters; read the manual for `fgets` for details on how to detect this.

The way it's written, you'll do one processing attempt per *line*, and the program stops when the input stream ends.

Comment: I think you mean just `fopen()`, not `std::fopen()`; the question is tagged [tag:c] not [tag:c++].

Comment: @BrianCampbell: Whoops, force of habit :-S

Answer (score 3):

When you pipe data from one program to another it's as if you typed the output of the first into the second.  In this case the file name can be read from stdin, and one way to read it is with the `fgets` function.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read from stdin, which means you could use `fread` (`man 3 fread` on *nix, [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fread.html) if you aren't.) to read from it.

`stdin` is just a name for a standard file-descriptor, so you can read from it like any other file.