# reading in filename using echo and using the file

Tags: c

I'm trying to use "`echo FileName.txt | a.c`" in terminal and read the data from the file into a array i got in a header file, but the code I have so far is just giving me a infinite loop. I tried storing the info in a local array also but still the same result.

```
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    extern char test[];
    FILE *fp;
    int i = 0;
    int c;       // was char c; originally
    if (argc == 1) {
        fp = stdin;
    } else {
        fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");
    }
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        test[i] = c;
        printf("%c", test[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `a.c` would normally be the C source code for a program, not the executable created from C source.  You should probably make `test` into a local array with a more descriptive name: `char filename[256];`.  You should ensure that you don't overflow the array (which means you must know how big it is).  You should null terminate the string.  You probably want to stop reading when you encounter newline (or EOF if you encounter EOF first). You should check that `fopen()` worked before using the pointer; users are notoriously bad at mistyping file names.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: He's using `test` to store the contents of the file, not a file name. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

(1) Change variable c to an int so it recognizes EOF.

(2) Don't increment i before your printf or you will be printing junk.

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the echo thing.

Comment: he is using a pipeline to send a filename to the program

Comment: I know but then he is only going to print the file name.

Comment: thanks I changed all that, and yes im trying to do what Smac69 said. i have to send the filename using echo then use it in the program, but im not exactly sure how to...

Comment: If this is posix you can use `isatty()` to determine if stdin is a terminal or a pipe.  (Not sure how windows does it.)  If it is not a pipe then the filename better be on the command line else it is an error. `if (! isatty(fileno(stdin))`...a pipe

Comment: Sorry, to be a little clearer, if it is a pipe read the filename string into an array.  If it is not a pipe then check and if the argv variable exists, copy that to the array.  Use the filename in the array in the `fopen` for the file you want to use.

Comment: @Duck: Changing a program's behavior depending on whether `stdin` is a tty is rarely a good idea. The usual behavior of Unixish programs is to read data either from `stdin` or from a file named by a command-line argument. That's pretty much what the code in the question does; it's just being invoked incorrectly.

Comment: @ Keith Thompson, you are right.  I was more focused on OP's immediate problem and lost the forest for trees.  I was confused on why he was doing it that way and assumed he had to do it so.  It didn't occur to me he might not be aware of normal practices.  My bad.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I'm assuming that your program is intended to do what the code in your question actually does, namely read input from a file named by a command-line argument, or from `stdin` if no command-line argument is given. That's a very common way for programs to operate, particularly on Unix-like systems. Your question and the way you invoke the program suggest that you're doing something quite different, namely reading a *file name* from standard input. That's an unusual thing to do. If that's really your intent, please update your question to clarify just what you're trying to do.

Given this assumption, the problem isn't in your program, it's in how you're invoking it.  This:

```
echo FileName.txt | a.c
```

will feed the string `FileName.txt` as input to your program; the program has no idea (and *should* have no idea) that it's a file name.

The way to pass a file name to your program is:

```
a.c FileName.txt
```

Or, if you want to read the contents of the file from `stdin`:

```
a.c < FileName.txt
```

(In the latter case, the shell will take care of opening the file for you.)

You *could* read a file name from `stdin`, but it's rarely the right thing to do.

A few other points (some already pointed out in comments):

An executable file probably shouldn't have a name ending in `.c`; the `.c` suffix indicates a C source file.

You should declare `main` with an explicit return type; as of C99, the "implicit `int`" rule was removed, and it was never a particularly good idea anyway:

```
main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

You're reading the entire contents of the input file into your `test` array. This is rarely necessary; in particular, if you're just copying an input file to `stdout`, you don't need to *store* more than one character at a time. If you do need to store the contents of a file in an array, you'll need to worry about not overflowing the array. You might want to abort the program with an error message if `i` exceeds the size of the array.

See also the rest of the advice in Jonathan Leffler's comment; it's all good advice (except that I think he misunderstood the purpose of your `test` array, which you're using to store the contents of the file, not its name).